# Do CLI guest OSes benefit from VirtualBox Guest Additions?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, command-line

What improvements Guest Additions provide for a CLI guest OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure guest additions are only for [Windows, Linux, and Solaris](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox). But if you're running Linux in CLI for example there are benefits to having guest additions installed:

- Easier mouse movement between the host and guest OS
- Sometimes USB does not respond, installing guest additions usually fixes this
- Time synchronization with the host OS
- Easier sharing of folders from the host OS

and probably more that would benefit CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you experience advantages but the guest additions need at least a X server to be installed on the system (because it tries to install window drivers).

Why downvote? All I can say is, that I have tried it, if there is an option to install the additions without an X server installed please tell me. I would be happy about that :)